# syspolicyd is killing my battery on a new MacBook Pro, repeatedly scanning and re-scanning my Steam library

Tags: battery, catalina, power, gatekeeper

syspolicyd is consistently using ~20% CPU and consuming lots of power.  Tracing it with `sudo fs_usage "$(pgrep syspolicyd)"` reveals that it's repeatedly scanning the same dozen or so Steam apps in my `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common` directory.

Is there any way to convince it to be less aggressive about scanning, or remind it that it's already scanned these locations?  Or at least get it to tell me why it's doing this without resorting to `dtrace` tooling?

Comment: Have you read this article: https://www.organizingcreativity.com/2020/12/syspolicyd-periodically-high-cpu-load-reading-huge-amounts-of-data-on-mac-big-sur-and-likely-catalina-as-well/

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It's really just describing the same problem, and doesn't have a solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems to be related to `syspolicyd` contacting Apple's iCloud services.

I have then turned off various iCloud services, including Photo synching. After that, it seems that `syspolicyd` has stopped running constantly.

What's left active in my case:

- iCloud Drive
- Safari
- Keychain
- Find My Mac

This suggests these were not the culprits.

I wouldn't be surprised if it's really the Photo sync service - I've had a similar issue on iOS two years ago where the iPhone apparently got stuck with some picture that it kept uploading endlessly, apparently due to some issue with it (and due to a bug in Apple's software, of course).

However, I don't see how that could relate to Steam and its files.

But perhaps you can, like I did, use Little Snitch to block all connections, and see if that helps. If it does, you may figure out what the problem is, too.

So, while this answer may not be particularly fitting to the question, others who search for problems with `syspolicyd` may find my answer helpful.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the I/O that is causing power drain is against `.app` bundles in my Steam library. How, exactly would this relate to iCloud or photos?  Wouldn't that be `cloudphotod` / `photolibraryd` ?

Comment: Also, `dtruss` suggests that the I/O is purely to disk, it's not talking to the network.