# `syspolicyd` CPU usage drains the battery

Tags: macos, battery, cpu, monterey, gatekeeper

Since I'm on Monterrey (from Mojave), there is **`syspolicyd` process ALWAYS using 35-45% on the CPU!**

If I leave the laptop in idle, `syspolicyd` (Apple Gatekeeper) consumes an average of 37% of the processor; NON-STOP.

This sometimes heats up and the fan to spin. But the main problem is that this **drains the battery of the laptop!**
I already have virtual machines or Docker or Kubernetes already sucking out all the power.
With this update and the arrival of `syspolicyd` I practically **cannot use my laptop as a mobile device!** The battery will be drained.

#### What I tried:

- suggestions from 2 StackExchange answers: *[syspolicyd is killing my battery on a new MacBook Pro, repeatedly scanning and re-scanning my Steam library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378796/syspolicyd-is-killing-my-battery-on-a-new-macbook-pro-repeatedly-scanning-and-r)*
  and *[syspolicyd producing huge amount of read on disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392521/syspolicyd-producing-huge-amount-of-read-on-disk)*
- I tried to use AppPolice to **limit the CPU usage**, adding `syspolicyd` [under `APApplicationLimits`](https://github.com/AppPolice/AppPolice/issues/23) but unfortunately it didn't help.
- I already tried to debug what files are accessed by the process, using `sudo lsof -c syspolicyd` but everything looks fine: looks like **it's accessing system files**; nothing from my personal files.
- I tried to **block `/usr/libexec/syspolicyd`** from keeping a 24/7 connection with Apple servers (they are continuously harvesting data from the users via `syspolicyd`), but that doesn't help either (looks like the TCP connection is still there, and Apple bypasses LuLu firewall). I blocked it in macOS Firewall but that doesn't do anything as well.

How do I prevent it from continuously hogging the CPU?
How do I eventually disable the service alltogether?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378796/syspolicyd-is-killing-my-battery-on-a-new-macbook-pro-repeatedly-scanning-and-r and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392521/syspolicyd-producing-huge-amount-of-read-on-disk

Comment: I already checked them & tried all the solutions there, thanks. Neither of those questions provide a working solution to the problem.

Comment: It's always best to document what you have researched & tried already - it saves duplicated effort.

Comment: @Kamafeather How long has this problem been going on for? - Is it a few hours, or weeks and months? - Does htis problem occur if you create a new user account and login as that user only?

Comment: With continuous use it goes on since a week, since I upgraded macOS.

Comment: My 2020 Intel Air has this exact problem. Monterey, syspolicyd *dominates* all other processes, even after a fresh restart with no opened applications. As i write this, syspolicyd is the top of Activity Monitor if i order by either CPU or CPU Time.

I should add, i have tried `renice`, `nice`, disabling gatekeeper entirely, manually allowed Dev and Full Disc Access to common apps, etc. Nothing i have tried seems to have a measurable impact.

Comment: I've finally found the issue and a solution!!  Check my answer below!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out!

## Solution

check in the *macOS* **Console.app**, filtering by `syspolicyd`.
There will be lines that are marked with a yellow dot .

Find those where is reported something like:

> Kernel Extension BLOCKED "com.malwarebytes.mbam.rtprotection"

or

> Kernel Extension BLOCKED "org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner.VirtualHIDDevice.v061000"

- In my case I've then found out that Malwarebytes' Kext was deprecated. Reinstalling fixed the extension.
- With Karabiner, the re-install triggered again the request to enable the extension in System Preferences.
  It finally asks to Allow the extension in "Preferences"->"Privacy & Security" ‼️

So, instead of cleaning manually, **just download and re-install the most recent version of the software providing the extension**, and suddenly **`syspolicyd` will drop to zero % CPU usage‼️**

---

## Rationale

Apparently **the issue is with extensions not being *Allowed***.
Even though I am sure I've checked several times in Privacy&Security, there was no sign of any requested extension (so the OS fails to keep a memory record about that required permission).

**This was leading the system to waste CPU cycles** trying to load an unprivileged extensions and fail, **cutting 1/3 of performance and battery life away**.

This **is a bug** in the OS  but hopefully this fix will finally improve a lot of users that were left grudging without a clue and a down-performing "upgraded" system.

Comment: Where exactly in the Console.app should I look? (which of the tabs in the sidebar)

Comment: Oh and what permission did Karabiner exactly need in your case? Maybe I can check and manually add it, I might face the same issue

Comment: Did you try to COMMAND+SPACE and type *"Console"*? Or looking into the `Applications` folder?

Comment: About Karabiner, the best way I found to retrigger the extension message is to uninstall and reinstall the app. This seems to be a standard procedure that worked and allowed me to fix with all the other apps that also have an extension.

Comment: Yes, I have the Console app open but I was asking about the tabs in the sidebar. I see about 6 types of "Reports". Which one should I search in?

Comment: I don't know the exact one, I filter through the main list (Devices->MacBook); or you might try `System.log`, honestly I can't remember but I don't think I ever had to choose a section: I simply Start Streaming the system events and then look through them, helping myself with the Search box or looking for the yellow circle mentioned in the answer. Sorry if I can't help you better.

Comment: Sadly I see errors but get no helpful info: `Unable to find URL for target: <private>`, or `error registering ticket: -1`, `Target is revoked: PST: (vuid: 7833708A-2328-4478-842F-5FA5CD7C41BF), (objid: 1254311), (team: (null)), (id: (null)), (bundle_id: (null))`, and `Unable to parse ticket.`. Would be superhelpful to have a modicum of additional info in Console app.

Comment: I can't help much, I'm not using macOS atm (and anyway the errors are already fixed). – I recall only by memory but...  try filtering the Console output with keywords like `syspolicyd`, or `Extension` or `kernel`, and look for entries that show a warning/error that are marked with yellow/red dot. Or try checking the other subsections in the left pane of Console. – **IF** extensions are the issue, then you'll find something by insisting in digging the logs.

Comment: If somebody else manages to fix the issue, hopefully they can update my answer with more details.